# Windows Form Window Always Focused?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, window, form-control

I know there are a few threads about this already. What I need is to have a windows form window always focused meaning if I click on notepad or whatever program it will not enter any data in it and only enter data in my windows form textbox.

I found this code which works somewhat will explain more

```
    //Delegates for safe multi-threading.
    delegate void DelegateGetFocus();
    private DelegateGetFocus m_getFocus;
    Thread newThread;

    public MemberLogin()
    {

        m_getFocus = new DelegateGetFocus(this.getFocus);  
        InitializeComponent();
        spawnThread(keepFocus);
        toggleFocusButton.Text = "OFF";
        timer1.Interval = 2000;
        textBox1.Select();
    }

    //test focus stuff
    //Spawns a new Thread.
    private void spawnThread(ThreadStart ts)
    {
        try
        {
            newThread = new Thread(ts);
            newThread.Start();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.Message, "Exception!", MessageBoxButtons.OK,
                MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }

    //Continuously call getFocus.
    private void keepFocus()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            getFocus();
        }
    }

    //Keeps Form on top and gives focus.
    private void getFocus()
    {
        //If we need to invoke this call from another thread.
        if (this.InvokeRequired)
        {
            this.Invoke(m_getFocus, new object[] { });
        }
        //Otherwise, we're safe.
        else
        {
            //having this seemed to have kept my windows onTop at all times even when off 
           // this.TopMost = true;
            this.TopMost = true;
            this.Activate();
            this.textBox1.Select();
            this.textBox1.Focus();

        }
    }
```

this code seems to work well only when my project is opened meaning when my Visual Studio Project is closed the window is top most but doesn't have focus meaning I can type inside other programs. Weird thing I found is that both notepad and my textbox had blinking line thing telling where you write the text. If I run my app from the Visual Studio project everything works as it should and when I try to click on other windows it won't let me access which is what I want.

So I'm a bit confused on why it only works properly with the project opened

Also note as long as the project is opened then even .exe and other copys I made work properly I close the project solution and the program does what I explained above.

Just did some more testing and it seems to only work properly when this process is running vhost.exe which is the Visual Studio hosting process. I disabled it in the settings, and when I launch from VS it works fine but when I run just the exe in the bin folder I still get the weird results

**EDIT**

Here's a quick video I made with my results http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1ozpHSRGnMo

**New Edit**

What I did to fix this was set my app in a fullscreen mode kinda by doing this so the user can go clicking on other windows without closing this one first

```
this.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
```

Comment: Windows has an explicit counter-measure in place to stop you from doing this.  Programmers never consider the obvious failure mode: what if *two* programs would do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Keeping an application on top and in focus - always](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2444842/keeping-an-application-on-top-and-in-focus-always)

Comment: Check out this video I just made showing the results http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1ozpHSRGnMo and no it's not a duplicate as I stated the code works and I got it from another post on this website. But the code only works when executed from VS2012 meaning when I press the F5 button to run my app. Like I can't even click on other windows, this is what I want! But then I run the exe and I can write in other windwows like notepad. So what I'm thinking is VS2012 is giving my app more priority over others somehow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot create a Windows Forms application that can stop other programs from gaining focus.  Windows itself will not allow this. The only way around this is to create an `OpenGL` or `DirectX` application in full screen mode. This will stop the user seeing any other application. But even with this, the user can `Alt+Tab` their way back to other applications.

Comment: Yea I think you're right about this. What I did to fix the issue is I kept my new thread making sure it's topmost all the time and I set borderstyle to none and maximized the window so it's like having it fullscreen witch fixes all issues thanks also I should add that alt tab doesn't work with this so perfect thanks again

Answer (score 5):

It's true you can't prevent that other windows gain focus, but you can take it from them the second they gain it ;)

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!this.Focused)
    {
        this.Activate();
    }
}
```

just create a timer, enable it from the start, make the tick interval as small as you want and put the code above as tick-event.

hope this helps

sry for the bad english

Comment: Oooh, how deliciously evil!

Answer (score 1):

your code seems fine and should work as you will, can you try something that is suggested in the following URL...just a suggestion though, instead of using the

```
this.TopMost = true;
```

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/kirtan007/make-form-stay-always-on-top-of-every-window/

Comment: Actually this worked but still didn't fix my focus problem. I can still write in notepad or any other software I have installed witch is what I'm trying to avoid. So when no one is at the PC and someone trys to sign in they won't be typing in the wrong window so I want my login screen focused at all times with the help of a button. This does work only when I run the project from VS2012 but when I run the exe it doesn't work as it should.