# AWT Frame in full-screen exclusive mode gets minimized on windows dialog popup

Tags: java, awt, fullscreen

i am developing an application which uses an awt frame in full-screen exclusive mode.
Everythings works fine until a windows popup gets visible.
This will steal the focus and my application will be minimized.

Here is my init code of the frame:

```
if (ApplicationConfig.getInstance().useFullscreenMode()) {
    frame.setUndecorated(true);
    frame.setResizable(false);

    if (monitor.isFullScreenSupported()) {
        monitor.setFullScreenWindow(frame);
        if (monitor.isDisplayChangeSupported()) {
            DisplayMode defaultMode = new DisplayMode(
                    (int) appDimension.getWidth(),
                    (int) appDimension.getHeight(),
                    32,
                    DisplayMode.REFRESH_RATE_UNKNOWN);

            monitor.setDisplayMode(defaultMode);
            frame.setFulscreenDisplayMode(defaultMode);

            DisplayMode selectedMode = monitor.getDisplayMode();
            log.debug("Setting fullscreen display mode to " + selectedMode.getWidth() + "x" + selectedMode.getHeight() +
                    " color depth: " + selectedMode.getBitDepth() + " refresh rate: " + selectedMode.getRefreshRate());
        } else {
            log.error("Change display mode not supported");
        }
    } else {
        log.error("Full screen not supported");
    }
}
```

Is there a workaround or setting to avoid this?

Comment: Thats pretty much how it *should* be. Any program attempting to block the interaction between OS and user is *malicious* - even if that isn't your intention here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the window manager usually doesn't enforce application window modality and for custom display mode application the wm is forced to either to drop you out of fullscreen or minimize as it cannot respect the dpi setting for the other window maintaining your own window resolution.

thee is a reason for that, explained [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2011/03/10/10138969.aspx) in the context of the Window O.S.

is this for some sort of kiosk system? then make your whole application the shell, as explained here: [Keeping a Windows application on top of other windows and in focus - always](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2444842/keeping-a-windows-application-on-top-of-other-windows-and-in-focus-always)

task manager will still pop in front of it, and alt tabbing should work as usual.

similar step for making a single app login in linux:
http://www.instructables.com/id/Setting-Up-Ubuntu-as-a-Kiosk-Web-Appliance/?ALLSTEPS

to disable usb fixing, see the answer to this question: https://superuser.com/questions/33986/is-it-possible-to-disable-the-scan-and-fix-message-when-inserting-an-sd-card

note that the first answer entail fixing the disk, if you scroll below there are the step to disable that specific dialog.

Comment: Hi Lorenzo, thank you in advance. Yes it would be for a kiosk solution. When i will replace the win shell my application will automaticaly be started at winlogon and will alwys be topmost right? This is not want i want at all. I must have to possibility to swtich back to desktop from my application and to another app which is running. I only want to prevent some windows dialogs to pop in front. How do most of the games achieve a window handling like this?

Comment: well, you would need to see who made that popup application and ask why it insists in stealing the focus out of you

Comment: on top of my head you could try making your own app into a modal dialog having APPLICATION_EXCLUDE - and you will need some in-app button to minimize it, and it won't work depending on how much aggressively the other dialog acts.

Comment: The dialog which steals my focus is the default windows dialog which is poping up, when you plug in certain usb sticks. "Scan and Fix errors" or something like this. I have already disabled the ballon tips for windows. But this dialog cannot be disabled.

Comment: so, if I have to take another guess, is that a photo printing kiosk?

Answer (score 0):

Setting the awt frame modality type fixed my problem.
As Lorenzo mentioned, using APPLICATION_EXCLUDE let the frame always be on top.
Thank you